# Badge counts on profile page communities section are misaligned

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

The badge counts on the **Communities** section of the profile page are misaligned; they should be moved down so that they are inline with the badge circles.

Here is a nice red freehand circle to illustrate what I mean:

[image: communities section of profile page with community hovered]

I have reproduced the issue on Chrome 84.0.4147.89, Chromium Edge 83.0.478.61 and Firefox Developer 79.0b2.

Comment: There seem to be [three different baselines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pjru.png). This is also reproducible in Firefox Nightly 80.0a1.

Answer (score 2):

In continuance of the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350865/badge-counts-on-profile-page-communities-section-are-misaligned#comment1174768_350865) by user289905; there are 4 elements at play here, of which only `span.profile-communities--rep-badges` and `span.badgecount` appear to have the same baseline. This is well illustrated in the screenshots below if you look at where the baseline intersects the logo part of Stack Overflow.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]