# Badges are vertically misaligned in communities list on hover

Tags: bug, design, badges, communities-list

The badges in communities list (aka *the bling*) seem to be misaligned vertically on hover.

[image]

For reference: a couple of months ago a bug was fixed [where the badges were cut off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364832) in the communities list. Last year [badges were also misaligned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350865) but down instead of up.

Using Firefox 92.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro.
rev 2021.10.4.40368

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This not necessarily a bug with the badges themselves - they are perfectly aligned on the font baseline (you will see they are if you measure them against the font-size of the element with the reputation count), just not the baseline the eye is expecting them to be aligned to.

The font-size of the badge count breakdowns is slightly smaller (12px) than the one for the reputation count (13px), so the badges appear to be misaligned by exactly 1 pixel.

---

If we inspect CSS, the alignment of badges in the primary stylesheet (taking bronze badges as an example) is set as follows:

```css
.badge3 {
    background-position: -62px -398px;
}
```

See the second value of the [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) rule? It is responsible for the slight vertical "misalignment" as it is a shorthand for the [`background-position-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position-y) property. The reason for it being setup this way is that the dots are displayed from a sprite sheet set in the corresponding [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) rule.

Here is the sprite sheet with the position of the badge icons highlighted:

[image: sprite sheet]

So, what can be done to address this?

**Approach #1: tweaking the alignment**

Given that the badge image is just a part of the sprite sheet, changing `background-position-y` slightly to `-397px` seemingly gives us the desired result when zoomed in:

[image: preview of the fix with background-position-y]

But once we zoom out, we find out that the badge is, unfortunately, too *low* visually:

[image: preview of the issue with the fix when zoomed out]

**Approach #2: using radial gradients**

Another solution is to create badges using [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient()) CSS function (since, well, they are *circles*) and then center the background:

```css
.badge3 {
    background-position: 50% 80%;
    background-image: radial-gradient(var(--bronze) 0px, var(--bronze) 30%, transparent 34%);
    background-size: 12px 12px;
}
```

Note that the color stops intentionally avoid "hard" stops due to [this old](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13467123/11407695) and, apparently, still unresolved bug in Chromium's rendering. Unfortunately, the solution suffers from shape changes on zoom out:

[image: preview of the shape changing to rotated rectangle on 100% zoom]

**Approach #3: using border-radius**

The third approach is the one taken by Stacks for the [badges](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/badges/) component perusing [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) and [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) rules:

```css
.badge3 {
    background-color: var(--bronze);
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

This, however, leads to a vertically elongated ellipsis being rendered as the context differs slightly, so we also have to make sure the background is clipped to a square box with [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) set to `content-box` + some `padding`:

```css
.badge3 {
    background-color: var(--bronze);
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-clip: content-box;
    padding: 4px 0px;
}
```

And here is how it would look like:

[image: preview of the fix using border-radius]

**Approach #4: clip-path**

Finally, one can use [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) with `background-color` to achieve the same result by drawing a [basic shape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Shapes/Basic_Shapes) at a cost of IE support:

```css
.badge3 {
    background-color: var(--bronze);
    clip-path: circle(3px at 50% 7px);
    background-image: none;
}
```

which results in:

[image: preview of the fix using clip-path]

**Approach #5: adjust font-size**

Of course, you can always just increase the `font-size` instead if that's your cup of tea:

```css
.badgecount {
    font-size: 13px;
    /* the rest of the properties */
}
```

resulting in:

[image: preview of the font-size change]

---

In any case, give it 6 to 8 weeks to be fixed and use what works best for you in the meantime.

Comment: No, it is nothing of this all. If you inspect closely you'll see that the two elements, the hover with the badges, and the site names, are not at the same height.

Comment: @Luuklag I was talking about the visual appearance - the size of the boxes is, indeed, different (14px - badge, 15.667px - badge count). The visual discrepancy bad_coder describes, however, is related to the difference between font sizes of the reputation count and badge count elements - the badges thus appear slightly misaligned.

Comment: as for the list of communities *positioned* on the Y axis lower than the hover element - yes, it is. However, it does not affect the badge positioning relative to the badge count (especially given that the background is set via background-image with a sprite sheet shifted on both X and Y axis).

Comment: @OlegValter I'm under the impression this is now fixed?

Comment: @bad_coder maybe? :) Let me check

Comment: @OlegValter would you believe it's working on SO using dark theme and not working on MSE using normal theme... :O

Comment: @bad_coder I would believe it :) Seems like the issue is definitely [not fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT5sI.png) on MSE but I can believe that it is ok on SO given that SO uses Stacks, and they used the approach described in #3 and thus avoid the issue altogether