# White circles overlap badge icons when viewing user profiles on mobile

Tags: bug, design, badges, profile-page, mobile-web

When viewing a user profile on a mobile site, the badge icons are overlayed with a white circle. This seems to happen across sites and badge types. I observed this both on Chrome 95.0 and Firefox 94.0.

A few examples:

Meta SE:
[image: Enthusiast badge with icon]

Math SE:
[image: Strunk & White badge with icon]

Aviation SE:
[image: Nice Answer badge with icon]

Looking at the page source, the difference between the desktop and mobile sites seems to be (for gold badges, in this example):

Desktop:

```html
<span class="badge1"></span>
```

Mobile:

```html
<span class="badge1">●</span>
```

Comment: I find this strangely reminiscent of [*"the bling"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370566) misalignment, elusive little dot isn't  it?! Always showing up where you least expect it...

Answer (score 5):

The mobile version of SE is not being developed by the developers anymore. So switch to the responsive version, click the "full site" button on the bottom of the page.

There are plenty of bugs about the mobile-web. Even on the [tag description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-web) it mentions:

> For questions about the (now deprecated) mobile versions of Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed this too. The solution is to go to the home page of the site, then tap on "full site" at the bottom. Since I have only seen this happen when viewing the new profile page with the old mobile site active, I doubt it will be fixed as the old mobile site is in the process of being removed.