# Misaligned dot next to unread custom question filters

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, custom-filters

The dot next to unread custom question filters is higher than it should be (not aligned vertically with the text).

[image: pic]

It should be ~2 pixels lower:

[image]

Comment: Elusive [little dot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370566) always misbehaving... Sometimes it even disappears completely.

Comment: I swear those dots were red a few hours ago...

Comment: @Warcupine now the dots are blue and look like circumference URLs...

Comment: Interestingly enough, the "new question" indicators for filters _haven't_ changed, so the two dot types don't match anymore: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UG75.png

Comment: Why did they change from red to blue at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This alignment fix will go out in the next build. Tomorrowish, probably. Thanks for pointing it out!

We switched to a new Stacks component, which is how indicators like this will look moving forward. By switching, it allows them to be themed, and the color red is generally reserved for errors.