# Can custom filter indicators have warmer colors than blue, and can there be more color variety in themes?

Tags: feature-request, design, custom-filters

After today's change in color of the filters indicator from red to blue, I think the site lost some of its design charm: it just looks *bland* and unappealing, since the same color is used throughout the page.

Also, because the indicators have the same color as the hyperlinks on the page, they're easy to overlook and be confused for clickable elements.

A brief explanation was given [in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372477) and I quote:

> We switched to a new Stacks component, which is how indicators like this will look moving forward. By switching, **it allows them to be themed, and the color red is generally reserved for errors.**

Can the color themes be updated to restore more color variety to the site? The old red color need not be restored, as it's reserved for errors, but can a different color be used for this indicator?

[image: screenshot of main page showing custom filters sidebar]

[image: screenshot of main page showing custom filters sidebar]

Comment: Customisation would also grant accessibility for various visually impaired users.